# Is there any way to manipulate config file of my project in phpunit?

Tags: php, phpunit, config

I am using phpunit for testing my project.

I collected all config file same directory called Config and my controller classes feed from this directory.

I am coding test codes by default config.

I must also code other config states but config files are static file as constant in class.

How can I manipulate config files to test in phpunit?